# SignalR loss of session sate/connections when publish to site, etc

Tags: signalr

I have an application that has an ASP.NET SingnalR server talking to a Windows Service backend SignalR client. Reports come from the client. Howeve3r, i a I do a Web Publish to the site, it wipes things out and I have to restart the client again. We have implemented reconnect logic but how can i store session state on the server and then retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to store the signalR connectionID in a a DB. See this http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections